# How to judge wireless network adapter by C#/mono on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono, wireless

there

I want to get a result that if there is wireless adapter on my Linux device by C#/mono.

If I use command "iwconfig" if wireless adapter attached, here is the result:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
```

if not attached,the result is :

```
 lo        no wireless extensions.

 eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

I want to **System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType** to get it,but it seem that for "eth0" and "wlan0", the return result both are "Ethernet".

So my question is there any other method to distinguish the wireless adapter? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do one of:

1. Check if the interface appears in `/proc/net/wireless`.
2. Create a socket and invoke `SIOCGIWNAME` on it, passing the interface name.
3. Attempt whatever wireless-specific task you want and see if it fails.

A possible solution for #2 is:

```
using System;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;

public class App
{
        public static int Main (string[] args)
        {
                NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
                Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Unspecified);
                foreach(NetworkInterface nic in nics)
                {
                        byte[] name = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(nic.Description);
                        byte[] request = new byte[32];
                        Array.Copy(name, request, name.Length);
                        bool wireless;
                        try
                        {
                                // SIOCGIWNAME is 0x8b01
                                socket.IOControl(0x8b01, request, request);
                                wireless = true;
                        } catch (SocketException) {
                                wireless = false;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} wireless={1}", nic.Description, wireless);
                }
                return 0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another answer,maybe not official, but does works.

```
    private Process _proCheckWLANInterface;
    private bool CheckWirelessAdapter()
    {
        bool flag = false;
        InitProcess(out _proCheckWLANInterface,"iwconfig","");
        string strResults = executeCmd(_proCheckWLANInterface);
        var datas = strResults.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (var item in datas)
        {
            if (item.Contains("IEEE 802.11"))
            {
                flag= true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                logger.Warn("Does not attached Wi-Fi Radio");
            }
        }
        return flag;

    }
    private void InitProcess(out Process pro,string cmd, string args)
    {
        pro = new Process();
        pro.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        pro.StartInfo.FileName = cmd;
        pro.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
        pro.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pro.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        pro.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    }
    private string executeCmd(Process pro)
    {
        try
        {
            pro.Start();
            pro.WaitForExit();
            //logger.Trace(pro.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            return pro.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Debug("Exception in executeCmd method:", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            pro.Close();
            pro.Dispose();
            pro = null;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: `iwconfig` executes the same `SIOCGIWNAME` ioctl I mentioned. Executing an external process isn't necessarily a good idea, it might not exist, might not be in the path or you might not have access. On the "pro" side, it does have a chance of working on non-linux systems too.